# Margin 0 Auto kicking float:right to a new line

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

Hey guys I'm trying to align 3 boxes horizontally with a little bit of white space in between. To do this I tried using float:left for the first box margin:auto for the middle one and float:right for the last box. The first two boxes display perfectly fine however the third one floats to the right on a new line. Is there anyway to fix this? Thanks!

Html:

```
    <div class="boxQ">
        <p class="boxText">quality.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="boxS">
        <p class="boxText">speed.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="boxSim">
        <p class="boxText">simplicity.</p>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.boxQ {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#C60;
}

.boxS {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:30%;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#6CC;
}

.boxSim {
    float:right;
    width:30%;
    height:400px;
    background-color:#FC6;

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just re-order your divs (no CSS changes needed) to be:

```
<div class="boxQ">
    <p class="boxText">quality.</p>
</div>
<div class="boxSim">
    <p class="boxText">simplicity.</p>
</div>
<div class="boxS">
    <p class="boxText">speed.</p>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NA83Y/)**

Comment: I think that would have been the last thin I would ever think of to fix this thanks! Can you explain why this works instead of my original one?

Comment: @kduan - sure, give me a minute and I'll add an explanation.

Comment: By placing the floated elements before the non-floated elements, you allow them to appear at the same position vertically, and also allow the non-floated div to float up and occupy the remaining space between then. With the original order of your elements, the non-floated element (speed) floated up to occupy the space next to the first floated element (quality), and then the last element (the simplicity div), which is floated, is forced below the non-floated element.